# How to write firestore rules for one to one chat app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I made a one to one chat app for a website using firebase and firestore. Now I want to write the firebase firestore rules for the same. The app works this way ...first if the user is sandeyshc@gmail.com then the user gets the chatids and friends gmails...then the user checks in the messages tab with chatids and get all the chat related details. Now I want to implement firestore rules for this app. How to implement it?

[image: users tab]

[image: messages tab]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve that is to use a combination of firestore rules and cloud functions.

First of all both users should have the same chat stored on different locations.
With the firestore rules you should restrict for each user to only change his own chat and only to be able to write his own messages in that chat.

When he writes his own message a cloud function should be triggered that sends a push notification to the other user and also writes that message to the chat of the other user by using admin rights in the cloud function.

That way both users have the same chat in different locations. You could do it also by giving them access to a single chat but consider in future the use case that one user can delete chats or messages. You probably don't want that one user can delete the messages from the other one.

Also one importand note: awoid saving users under they're `email`. You should store them always under the Application Auth User Uid. Emails can have `chars` that are not supported as database keys and you can get in other different bugs in future by using the email.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/tree/master/packages/rmw-shell) of a open source chat app made in react and firebase. It uses the realtime database but you can easyly reuse the concept. You can see there how the functions are written and how to use it on the frontend.

Comment: can you run this on codesandbox? I am getting an error over there
https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/tree/master/packages/rmw-shell?codemirror=1